# Как сделать файловый менеджер Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

Я хочу чтоб при нажатии кнопки для загрузки картинки или другого файла открывался файловый менеджер как допустим на WordPress. Как это сделать?
Есть CKFinder но я так и не понял как его использовать отдельно от CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка для скачивание ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/

Подключение:

```
$this->registerJsFile('/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');<br>
$this->registerJsFile('/ckfinder/ckfinder.js');
```

Вызов:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var editor = CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
   CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CKeditor - это WYSIWYG редактор, а если нужно файловый менеджер (по subj) то вам предлагаю elfinder , есть для Laravel-а wrapper https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder